# What happened to the third "Dalek" movie?

Tags: movie, doctor-who, dalek, reference

In the Wikepedia article on [Daleks – Invasion Earth: 2150 A.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daleks_%E2%80%93_Invasion_Earth:_2150_A.D.#cite_note-sfx.co.uk-6), it is stated that a third Dalek movie was considered but was never realised. The claim is that it was to be based upon the serial The Chase. However, only one reference is given (that seems to have moved to [here](http://www.gamesradar.com/the-dalek-movies-from-the-sfx-archives/), still the same site but difficult to find from link given).

I've seen some clips that suggested some filming had taken place, but these seem clearly faked. My question is, **are there any references that give more details of the potential third film (the referenced site just quotes no sources)?**

Comment: There was a 30th Anniversary documentary film for those; [Dalekmania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalekmania) which was also released with the films in a 3 disc set (in North America at least).

Comment: I'd like to think that the second dalek movie (combining the plot of "The Dalek Invasion of Earth," one of the worst Doctor Who serials ever, with the atrocious acting of the first dalek movie) would have killed the movie franchise.  But, realistically, dalekmania probably knew no bounds.  I suppose I shouldn't talk, having had daleks atop my wedding cake and having pewter dalek salt and pepper shakers that I use for special occasions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The faked clip mentioned by the OP is probably this "[trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=josI9YR45dI)", which created a [myth](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Chase_(TV_story)#Myths):

> A third Dalek film starring Peter Cushing, based on DW: *The Chase* and
>   titled *Daleks vs. Mechons*, was filmed but subsequently lost in a fire.
>   A trailer was discovered in the basement of a church in northern
>   England in 2009. *(The supposed "trailer" was fanmade, as the graphics
>   were too advanced for circa 1967. Although a third film was planned as
>   an adaptation of The Chase, it was shelved with no work done following
>   the second movie's failure at the box office.)*

AARU productions had the rights to make a third film, and were going to base it on *The Chase*, but it was "abandoned following the poor box office reception of the second film", according to 
Wikipedia's entry *[Dr. Who (Dalek films)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Who_(Dalek_films))*, which references *[The Official Doctor Who & the Daleks Book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Official-Doctor-Who-Daleks-Book/dp/0312022646/)* by John Peel and Terry Nation.

(Another [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unmade_Doctor_Who_serials_and_films#Daleks_vs._Mechons) says that the film was to be called *Daleks vs. Mechons*
according to Doctor Who Magazine issue 461, July 2013.  They might have got that title wrong, because the fake clip was uploaded in 2010 and I haven't found any earlier source confirming it.)

I have *[Doctor Who: 25 Glorious Years](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Doctor-Who-25-Glorious-Years/dp/1852270217/)* by Peter Haining, which says (pp. 106-7):

> Although [Milton Subotsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milton_Subotsky) had the rights to produce a third
>   *Doctor Who* movie, the lack of success of the second picture has so far deterred him from doing so - although Tom Baker did bring him a
>   project in 1975 called *Doctor Who Meets Scratchman*, which was based
>   on a completely new script that he had devised with his co-star in the
>   TV series, [Ian Marter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Marter).

*[Doctor Who Meets Scratchman](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Who_Meets_Scratchman)* would have featured scarecrows "animated when a fertiliser on Earth goes horribly wrong" and also Daleks, Cybermen and Vincent Price as the villain.  It was never made because "the proposed £500,000 budget couldn’t be raised", according to the Peter Cushing Association's page on [Doctor Who films](http://www.petercushing.co.uk/historydrwho.htm), which concludes:

> Milton Subotsky tried in vain many times throughout the seventies and
>   eighties to get his third Dalek film made. So far nothing is
>   forthcoming. Unless you count the awful Paul McGann TV movie in 1996.
>   However, a company called Chaos Films Plc now owns the film rights and
>   we may see something yet.

A book, *[The Nth Doctor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nth-DOCTOR-Jean-Marc-Lofficier/dp/0595276199)*, is about seven other ideas for Doctor Who films that were never made.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there may have been a third Doctor film about the Voord according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voord):

> Amicus Productions, which made two Dalek movies, acquired the movie rights to The Keys of Marinus but the movie was never made.

This is attributed to a book "Terry Nation (The Television Series)" by Jonathan Bignell and Andrew O'Day (published by Manchester University Press).

Comment: It should be noted that it is *very* common for movie rights for a book to be purchased (usually for a nominal fee + future royalties if the film is ever made) and then nobody ever actually does anything with it.  Amicus Productions, it seems, certainly never did anything with those rights, and who knows who owns them (if they even still exist) now?